# How to find the eigenvalues of the linear transformation that takes circle to ellipse

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

I have the following question,

How to find the eigenvalues of the linear transformation $$T:\mathbb{R}^2\rightarrow \mathbb{R}^2$$ that takes the circle $$C=\{(x,y):x^2+y^2=1\}$$ to ellipse $$E=\{(x,y): {x^2\over 9} + {y^2 \over 4}=1\}$$ Options are

(1) $1,-1$

(2) $3,2$

(3) $-3,-2$

(4) None of the above

**My Efforts**

First we write the circle and ellipse in the parametric form, $$C=\{(\cos(t), \sin(t)): t \in (-\pi, \pi]\}$$
$$E=\{(3\cos(t), 2\sin(t)): t \in (-\pi, \pi]\}$$

But how do I know what $T$ is and how does it act on $\mathbb{R}^2$

Comment: **Hint**: the vectors $(1,0)$ and $(0,1)$ will be eigenvectors.

Comment: @AnuragA So $3$ and $2$ will be eigenvalues and that means (1,0) is mapped to (3,0) but why? Why T can not take (1,0) to another point

Comment: @AnuragA I think I have to show that every linear transformation which takes circle to ellipse takes (1,0) to (3,0) and (0,1) to (0,2)

Comment: @AnuragA What about $T(x,y)=(-3y,2x)$?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are infinitely many such $T$. One of them is diagonal and has eigenvalues $2,3$. Another is, as already mentioned in a comment, $T(x,y)=(-3y,2x)$, which has no real eigenvalues. So it's a bad question - if it actually  asks about "*the*" $T$ that takes the circle to that ellipse it's a very bad question.

Comment: After your answer, I rechecked the problem. It was posted on a facebook mathematics page. It may be wrong. I understand your point. While this question was posted here, I proved that if we have a symmetric matrix, it sends circle to ellipse. Am I right?

Comment: @StammeringMathematician Actually, _every_ nonsingular linear transformation maps the unit circle to an ellipse.

Comment: @StammeringMathematician As amd pointed out, any nonsingular linear transformation maps the unit circle to _some_ ellipse. More relevant to the current problem:  If we assume that $T$ is symmetric and maps the unit circle to the _given_ ellipse then there are only four possibilities for $T$ instead of infinitely many (the diagonal matrices  with entries $\pm 3$ and $\pm 2$ on the diagonal...)